# why :in-range select input that has not value

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I try to use ":in-range" CSS pseudo-class, I create an input with type of number without value and I assume that the input has no value so it should be invalid or out-of-range but it selected with ":in-range", is it a correct behaviour ? also I select input with JQuery and it shows empty string for input and I think empty string should not be between 5 and 10 that I wrote in my code.what is your suggestion for use ":in-range" for input without value.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#showVal").click(function(){
   let val = $("#input").val();
   alert(val);
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="number"]:out-of-range{
  background-color:red;
}
input[type="number"]:in-range{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input" type="number" min="5" max="10"/>

<button id="showVal">Show Value</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, `:out-of-range` doesn't work for empty input.
My suggestion would be to add `:invalid` pseudo-class as well.

> The :invalid CSS pseudo-class represents any  or other 
>   element whose contents fail to validate.

However the input must be set to **required**.
Then, if the input is empty, it would be considered invalid and the same CSS for `:out-of-range` can be applied.

```
input[type="number"]:invalid{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```
<input id="input" type="number" min="5" max="10" required />
```